# Setting up WebSphere Liberty Profile HTTP Access Logging

Tags: logging, websphere-liberty

I am trying to enable HTTP access logging for requests to my application running on WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.2.  I have tried adding the logging configuration globally as well as in the specific HTTP endpoint.  In all attempts, the http_access.log file is created, but no data is ever logged.  I am also assuming that HTTPS access requests will also be logged, since that is still HTTP, over an encrypted connection.  I have tried basic auth requests over http and https.  Here is a snip from my server.xml.  I am using most of the defaults.

```
<logging maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="10"/>
<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="HTTPS">
   <sslOptions/>
   <accessLogging maxFiles="10"/>
</httpEndpoint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this endpoint starts correctly, what you have should work.

Note that the defaultHttpEndpoint also listens on those ports. Are you sure that your endpoint (with id="HTTPS") is binding to those ports correctly?

I use the following, note that I'm overriding/extending the default endpoint (id="defaultHttpEndpoint") to enable remote access and http access logging:

```
<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint">
    <accessLogging/>
</httpEndpoint>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had only 1 endpoint specified named "AM", but it seems that I needed it to be called defaultHttpEndpoint for the access log to work.  I speculate that "defaultHttpEndpoint" was still being created as a default endpoint, and that was grabbing the http_access.log file.

Comment: Right. defaultHttpEndpoint will start, and was likely binding to the ports. Since defaultHttpEndpoint does not log by default, your requests were being served, but were being served by something that wasn't logging. ;)

<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" enabled="false" /> will turn off the default endpoint, such that whichever others you define can be used instead.